# COVID Data api calculate the daily cases from api that returns commutative cases by subtracting from previous object value

Tags: arrays, json, vue.js, object

I have been working on a COVID-19 dashboard where I want to display the daily cases and daily deaths in the line graph. I can get the data from the following api https://api.covid19api.com/total/dayone/country/United%20Kingdom but it return me the total commutative cases and total commutative deaths on the given date. The data returned is in the following structure

```
 const data = [ 
 {
"Country": "United Kingdom",
"CountryCode": "",
"Province": "",
"City": "",
"CityCode": "",
"Lat": "0",
"Lon": "0",
"Confirmed": 190584,
"Deaths": 28734,
"Recovered": 0,
"Active": 161850,
"Date": "2020-05-04T00:00:00Z"
},
{
"Country": "United Kingdom",
"CountryCode": "",
"Province": "",
"City": "",
"CityCode": "",
"Lat": "0",
"Lon": "0",
"Confirmed": 194990,
"Deaths": 29427,
"Recovered": 0,
"Active": 165563,
"Date": "2020-05-05T00:00:00Z"
},
{
"Country": "United Kingdom",
"CountryCode": "",
"Province": "",
"City": "",
"CityCode": "",
"Lat": "0",
"Lon": "0",
"Confirmed": 201101,
"Deaths": 30076,
"Recovered": 0,
"Active": 171025,
"Date": "2020-05-06T00:00:00Z"
}
]
```

Where Confirmed is the total number of cases detected on that day. To calculate the daily cases on the specific day we can subtract the confirmed from the previous confirmed of previous date. For example 2020-05-05 the number of cases confirmed on that day can be calculated by subtracting the number of cases on 20-05-04 the previous day. So the calculation would be 194990- 190584 = 4442. For the first object of the array the value stays the same since there is no previous record to subtract from as I will be fetching the day one when a case was detected in that country. Therefore the desired data would be the following

```
const desiredData= [ 
 {
"Country": "United Kingdom",
"CountryCode": "",
"Province": "",
"City": "",
"CityCode": "",
"Lat": "0",
"Lon": "0",
"Confirmed": 190584,
"Deaths": 28734,
"Recovered": 0,
"Active": 161850,
"Date": "2020-05-04T00:00:00Z"
},
{
"Country": "United Kingdom",
"CountryCode": "",
"Province": "",
"City": "",
"CityCode": "",
"Lat": "0",
"Lon": "0",
"Confirmed": 4442,
"Deaths": 29427,
"Recovered": 0,
"Active": 165563,
"Date": "2020-05-05T00:00:00Z"
},
{
"Country": "United Kingdom",
"CountryCode": "",
"Province": "",
"City": "",
"CityCode": "",
"Lat": "0",
"Lon": "0",
"Confirmed": 6111,
"Deaths": 30076,
"Recovered": 0,
"Active": 171025,
"Date": "2020-05-06T00:00:00Z"
}
]
```

I am using Vue.js I think this could be a basic javascript function which can loop through the array and subtract the "Confirmed" of current object from the "Confirmed" of previous object. Please do let me know how this can be acheived. Many Thanks

Comment: What did you try on this? Can you share it, please?

Comment: Hi @SMAKSS. I have marked the correct answer. The solution below works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
result = data.map((record, index, allRecords) => {
    const previous = allRecords[index - 1] || {
        Confirmed: 0
    }
    return {
        ...record,
        newConfirmed: record.Confirmed - previous.Confirmed
    }
});
```

Which will give you a result such as this which includes the "newConfirmed" key and value:

```
[{
    "Country": "United Kingdom",
    "CountryCode": "",
    "Province": "",
    "City": "",
    "CityCode": "",
    "Lat": "0",
    "Lon": "0",
    "Confirmed": 190584,
    "Deaths": 28734,
    "Recovered": 0,
    "Active": 161850,
    "Date": "2020-05-04T00:00:00Z",
    "newConfirmed": 190584
}, {
    "Country": "United Kingdom",
    "CountryCode": "",
    "Province": "",
    "City": "",
    "CityCode": "",
    "Lat": "0",
    "Lon": "0",
    "Confirmed": 194990,
    "Deaths": 29427,
    "Recovered": 0,
    "Active": 165563,
    "Date": "2020-05-05T00:00:00Z",
    "newConfirmed": 4406
}, {
    "Country": "United Kingdom",
    "CountryCode": "",
    "Province": "",
    "City": "",
    "CityCode": "",
    "Lat": "0",
    "Lon": "0",
    "Confirmed": 201101,
    "Deaths": 30076,
    "Recovered": 0,
    "Active": 171025,
    "Date": "2020-05-06T00:00:00Z",
    "newConfirmed": 6111
}]
```